# can't push to array Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have problem with array Objects.
I have variable "setting".
If I write:

```
var settings=[];
var tempSettings=[{
   id:1,
   name:"Test1"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name:"Test2"
   }
];
settings=tempSettings;
console.log(settings[0]);
```

All right-all work. settings[0]- no problem;

But if I received data from file and do:

```
 jQuery.getJSON("myurl", function(data) {
console.log(data);                  
var zones=data.split("~");          
jQuery.each(zones, function(key, value) {
          var set = value.split(",");
          var tset={
                  id:set[0],
                  name:set[1]
               };

          settings.push(tset);         
    }); 
});
console.log(settings[0]);
```

This not work settings[0] - undefined.
What my mistake?

Data I received and console.log(data);  get me string data.

**Added:**

console.log(tempSettings) in variant hardcodded does:

[Object { Id=1, name="Test1"},Object { Id=2, name="Test2"} ]

and console.log(settings) in received variables does: 
[].

but in after click in console I see:

[0] Object { id="3", name="Test3"}, [1] Object { id="4", name="Test4"}.

Comment: It's likely that whatever data you're splitting on `~` does not have anything to iterate over. I would inspect what's in `data` to make sure it has something you expect.

Comment: Do you have a sample of data that you receive from the server?

Comment: I can only presume that what you're returning from your server is not valid JSON. The `data` passed to the callback of `.getJSON` should be an object, not a string.

Comment: You're missing the closing `});` from your `getJSON` in that code btw.

Comment: what does `console.log(set[0]);` and `console.log(set[1]);` output? also, jQuery.getJSON is not closed properly

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON?

Comment: Why don't you  put `console.log(zones)` after `var zones=data.split("~"); ` as debugging effort

Comment: in console.log I see tset: 
Object { id="3", name="Test3"}
I received data.

Answer (score 1):

`getJSON` is asynchronous. You need to include the `console.log` within the callback function:

```
jQuery.getJSON("myurl", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var zones=data.split("~");
  jQuery.each(zones, function(key, value) {
    var set = value.split(",");
    var tset = {
      id:set[0],
      name:set[1]
    };
    settings.push(tset);         
  });
  console.log(settings[0]);
});
```

Comment: console.log(tempSettings) in variant hardcodded does: 
[Object { Id=1, name="Test1"},Object { Id=2, name="Test2"} ] and  console.log(settings) in received variables does: []. but in after click in console I see: [0] Object { id="3", name="Test3"}, [1] Object { id="4", name="Test4"}.